# how can i exit for loop inside if statement

Tags: python

i'm coding  bulls and cows by python.
here is my code.
i want re-input if i get a not a number or over or under unit digit.
for example if i input '1, a , 2', i need to go back to input line but other numbers but because of other numbers '1'and'2', it goes else line and while statement will end.please help me.sorry about bad English

```
flag=0

while flag==0:
num=[0]
num=input('Input 3 number(ex: 1, 2, 3) : ').split(', ')

  for i in range(3):
    if(len(num)>3):
      print('Only input 3 number')
      break
    elif(num[i].isdigit()==False):
      print('Input only a Number')
      break
    elif(int(num[i]<0 or int(num[i]>9):
      print('out of number range')
      break
    else:
      flag=1
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
while True:
    num=input('Input 3 numbers (ex: 1, 2, 3) : ').split(', ')

    if(len(num)==3):
        if num[0].isnumeric() and num[1].isnumeric() and num[2].isnumeric():
            break
        else:
            print('Input only numbers')
    else:
        print('Input 3 numbers')
```

Comment: thanks but how to do if i input 1, 2, 10 ?

Comment: try:

if (num[0].isnumeric() and int(num[0]) <= 9) and (num[1].isnumeric() and int(num[1]) <= 9) and (num[2].isnumeric()and int(num[2]) <= 9):

Comment: Thank you i solve it. but i have a question can't i use 'for statement' for looks clearly?

Answer (score 0):

There were two parentheses missing in this line

```
elif (int(num[i] < 0 or int(num[i] > 9):
```

it should look more like this:

```
elif (int(num[i]) < 0 or int(num[i]) > 9):
```

The indentation of the code probably went weird when you uploaded it at Stack overflow, but don't forget that in Python, indentation matters

This is my version of the code and it works just fine!

```
flag = 0

while flag == 0:
    num = [0]
    num = input('Input 3 number(ex: 1, 2, 3) : ').split(', ')
    for i in range(3):
        if (len(num) > 3):
            print('Only input 3 number')
            break
        elif (num[i].isdigit() == False):
            print('Input only a Number')
            break
        elif (int(num[i]) < 0 or int(num[i]) > 9):
            print('out of number range')
            break
        else:
            flag=1
```

Comment: oh that was my mistake when i post.  i did the same as like you. if i  input 1, 2, 10 it doesn't work